# How do I keep a variable consistant even after seperate play sessions?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, air

I have a variable `area` which stores a number.

When the app is restarted, it is reset back to it's original value.  How can I keep `area` persistent after being closed?

I'm using Flash CS6 for Android

Comment: Store the variable in a shared object http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to save the variable. There's multiple ways to do this but using a [SharedObject](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html) is the easiest IMO.

First thing is you don't actually create a new instance of the `SharedObject` class, you instead call the static function `getLocal` and this sets your variable. So somewhere near the start of your program you'll want something like this:

```
var gameSave:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("gameSave");
```

This either creates a new locally persistent shared object if one does not exist or it grabs the one with the same initialized name ("gameSave") on your computer. This way you can access the saved variables across multiple playthroughs.

Now to save a variable you simply use the `data`Object on the shared object and write values to it, then you call the function `flush` when you're done writing values to immediately save the shared object to your computer.

So saving your area value would look something like this:

```
gameSave.data.area = Main.area;
gameSave.flush();
```

After that you'll want to set the `area` value to whatever the saved value is when your game launches:

```
if (gameSave.data.area !== undefined) Main.area = gameSave.data.area;
```

We check if the value is `undefined` because it might not exist yet if you're playing the game for the first time and the area hasn't been saved yet.

Last thing in case you want to expand the scope of this and save more values: you can only write specific values to the shared object. The way I understand it is you can only write certain class types and primitives. If you try to write anything that's not a primitive or the exception classes, it'll automatically convert that item to an `Object` and it more or less becomes useless. The classes that it can accept that you'll probably use the most are: `int`, `uint`, `Number`, `String`, `Boolean`, `Object`, and `Array`. It has a few others like `ByteArray` and `XML`, but you'll either not use those at all or not use them very frequently. If you want to save any other class type you'll have to add that functionality yourself.